# Verify email in SES as part of Cognito verification

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

How can you verify emails in SES once it is verified in Cognito? Expected behaviour is when user registers via Cognito, they receive verification email. After clicking on verification link user will be verified both in **Cognito** and **SES**.

I would be happy if I could even do the same with SNS

**UPDATE**
For whom are interested, I had my SES account under sandbox. Of course in production I can send emails to my Cognito user pool with asking them to register again in SES

Comment: You mean you are not able to send verification email even though you have set FromEmail in cognito?

Comment: User needs to verify email as part of Cognito registration, but they also need to do the same thing for SES when they added to the list. I am looking for a way to send only one verification email to register user in Cognito AND SES

Comment: Well, I don't understand your requirement clearly. But what we are doing is we are giving permission to cognito in the `SES Identity policy` with `cognito-idp.amazonaws.com`
Using this the cognito can directly use this email in their configuration and auto verification email should work fine!

Comment: You need to verify SES recipients only when your SES account is in `sandbox` state as AWS wants to make sure you understand implications of utilising this service. When going to production you need to request for limit increase. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: @PeterPajchl Such a simple oversight! Thank you!

Comment: yeah I think I've tried and failed at this several times myself.  Start making SNS topics and decide if you want to use SQS or Subscribe a post to a Lambda and maintain bounces, complaints, rejects etc.  I still get confused with the chicken or egg setup with Cognito and SES and how to manage folks unsubscribing.

Answer (score 0):

I am little confused with your question, but I am assuming you are having a problem sending emails to users through SES. If I am wrong, please elaborate your question little more.

There is no need to verify user's email address in SES.  Maybe SES is restricting you to send emails globally. By default, to send emails through SES the receiver email must be registered, AWS is responsible for this behavior. You have to ask AWS support team to open the account to allow sending emails to any receiver address.